# How many threads does ClickHouse use when inserting data into a distributed table in synchronous mode?

Tags: insert, clickhouse

I want to figure out how many threads does ClickHouse use when it inserts some data into a distributed table, is there any configurations or settings to make this? I have a cluster which has 3 servers, a local table(engine: ReplicatedMergeTree) which has 3 shards and 2 replicas, a distributed table which points to this local table. I want to insert some data into this distributed table by synchronous mode(internal_replication=true, insert_distributed_sync=true, insert_quorum=2).

I've read the documents of ClickHouse and known that `background_pool_size` sets the number of merge threads and `async_insert_threads` is used in async mode instead of sync mode, which in my case. `max_threads` is used in query, not in insert. `max_insert_threads` is used in `INSERT SELECT`, not in insert.

Comment: try look to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_thread_log/